# Есть ли способ изменить размер фрейма видео не меняя собственно картинки?

Tags: видео, ffmpeg

Добрый день.

Есть `mkv` файл с размером видео **960*408**. Нужно получить `mkv` файл с размером видео **1024*424** заполняя свободное место черным цветом и так, чтобы исходная картинка не была изменена/перекодирована.

Может ли это сделать с помощью `ffmpeg`?

Поиск дает вариант:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv  -vf "pad=width=1024:height=424:x=32:y=3:color=black" 
output.mkv
```

Но, по видимому, происходит перекодировка, т.к. процесс длится долго.

Если `ffmpeg` это не позволяет, то возможно ли это в принципе?

Answer (score 0):

Короткий ответ: нет и нет.

Ваш вариант - это фильтр. Фильтры в FFmpeg работают только с раскодированными данными. С закодированными данными могут работать только т.н. Bitstream фильтры, но возможности их ограничены.

А по сути, каждый последующий байт закодированного фрейма зависит от соседей, а теперь просто представьте, как бы вы добавили поля слева и справа да так, что бы декодер не сошёл с ума. Это всё равно, что дописать в текстовый файл в ZIP архиве текст, пришлёпывая что-то по бокам к самому ZIP архиву. Это ответ на вопрос - "можно ли в принципе?".

Что-то похожее можно было бы сделать, добавить просто ещё один видео стрим с чёрной картинкой, но это нужна поддержка со стороны проигрывателя, что бы он как-то понял, что нужно отобразить чёрный стрим, а по верх него уже другой стрим, да ещё и в нужном положении... Но если он (проигрыватель) обладает таким знанием, то смысл второго стрима сразу теряется - можно сразу рисовать на большем полотне нужную картинку :)

Можно попробовать пришлёпать свои методанные к стриму, типа геометрии и смещения, что бы целевой проигрыватель понял, что нужно рисовать по другому, но это тоже нужна поддержка со стороны проигрывателя.

Answer (score 0):

Практическое применение: нет, не получится.

Теоретическая возможность: да

К примеру, внутри контейнера AVI (про другие не скажу), есть указание размера канваса и оффсеты, где именно крутить это видео. Можно взять хекс-редактор и поправить заголовок ручками. Другое дело, что это ни один из известных мне плееров не поддерживает, а разработчики, которые порой все же читают документацию, переодически впадают во фрустрацию от этого мира (можно перечитать мемуары Эвери Лии), а потом просто игнорят такую информацию из заголовка как и все остальные, предпочитая сделать проект "шобы работало", не заморачиваясь на фишки конкретного формата, которые к тому же никто не использует.